# Makefile for potentially large project with automatic target creation

Tags: c, makefile, gnu

Let's say I have a C project. There are several files:

```
/myproject/makefile
/myproject/src
/myproject/build
/myproject/src/baseHeader.h
/myproject/src/module1/module1.h
/myproject/src/module1/module1_a.c
/myproject/src/module1/module1_b.c
/myproject/src/main.c
```

I want make to search in src for all *.h files which are not on the first depth level i.e. make should look for *.h files in

```
/myproject/src/module1/
```

so it will not use

```
/myproject/src/baseHeader.h
```

Then for every found .h make should create target with the basename of .h i.e. for

```
/myproject/src/module1/module1.h
```

it should be

```
./build/module1.o: ./src/module1/module1_a.c ./src/module1/module1_b.c ./src/module1/module1.h $(OTHER_DEPS) | $(OPTIONAL_DEPS)
        $(CC) -c $< -o $@
```

also it should create target for every .c file in /myproject/src/ dir without going recursive in this example only main.c will be found and target should look like

```
./build/main.o: ./src/main.c $(OTHER_DEPS) | $(OPTIONAL_DEPS)
```

How this can be done?
Could someone provide me with the link to example if exists?

I'm asking for this because after a day of trying I think it's better to forget about make and use bash scripts instead...

Comment: You can absolutely do this with make it just needs a little bit of work.

Comment: Is the hierarchy under `src` arbitrarily deep or just one level deep?

Comment: Etan Reisner, arbitrary

Comment: Common practice in using `make` has always been to just build everything in the source directory/ies and have a separate `make install` to copy the results over into their final destination. Going against this will not only cause trouble for you but also confuse whoever is using your makefile(s).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done but it is not trivial. One way to do it is to build a list of all of the `.h` files recursively in the `src` directory and its subdirectories, then remove from that list the `.h` files in the `src` directory.

We can search the src directory and all subdirectories for `.h` files with `$(wildcard src/**/*.h))` and only the src directory for `.h` files with $(wildcard src/*.h). These can be combined with the [filter-out](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Text-Functions.html#Text-Functions) function to produce a list containing only the `.h` files in subdirectories of `src/` like

```
MODULES := $(filter-out $(wildcard src/*.h),$(wildcard src/**/*.h))
```

This will produce a list like

```
/myproject/src/module1/module1.h
/myproject/src/module2/module2.h
/myproject/src/module3/module3.h
```

We could remove the directory structure with

```
INCLUDES := $(notdir MODULES)
```

which will produce

```
module1.h
module2.h
module3.h
```

We can convert these into object files for the modules with

```
OBJDIR = build
OBJS := $(addprefix $(OBJDIR)/, $(patsubst %.h,%.o, $(INCLUDES)))
```

Then we define an empty target rule to create all these

```
.PHONY: modules    
modules: $(OBJS)
```

And the implicit rule to create the objects

```
$(OBJDIR)/%.o: $(dir $(findstring %.h, $MODULES))*.c %.h $(OTHER_DEPS) | $(OPTIONAL_DEPS)
    $(CC) -c $? -o $@
```

**EDIT:** Its not particularly advisable to use wildcards in prerequisite lists but it is the best solution I have for now.

To compile a target for every `.c` file in `src` without searching recursively we take a similar approach starting off.

```
SRCS := $(wildcard src/*.c)
```

will find all out the `.c` files in the top level `src` directory. We can compile targets for these with

```
$(SRCS:%.c=$(OBJDIR)/%.o): %.c $(OTHER_DEPS) | $(OPTIONAL_DEPS)
```

Comment: You don't want to be using wildcards in the prerequisite lists of targets. That has surprising consequences.

Comment: `.PHONY: modules` and removing the `touch modules` recipe is likely better also.

Comment: Have you tested that the `**` glob works here? Because I don't believe make supports that (and it doesn't use the shell, which might support it, for `$(wildcard)` usage).

Comment: @EtanReisner `.PHONY: modules` will work too. I wrote most of the answer from memory and blanked on that part and used `touch modules` as a stop gap. I'll edit the answer now, thanks for pointing it out. I've used the `**` glob previously and it works with GNU Make 4.x. I think it works on 3.8.2 and up. I know you shouldn't use wildcards in the prerequisite lists of targets but that was the quickest and easiest solution I could think of at the time.

Comment: I tried it in make 3.81 and 4.1 on CentOS 5 and it didn't work here. I suppose it might work on newer systems that have shells that support `**` if it shells out for that internally (when it needs to) but I don't know that it does. And "quick and easy but broken" (especially when that's not mentioned as a caveat) isn't something you really want in a good answer.

Comment: @EtanReisner I'm open to editing the answer if you have a better solution? It would probably teach me a thing or two also.

Comment: My project will run only on newer systems with GNU Make 4.x, so ** is not a problem...

Comment: Yeah, I just need to find the time to sit down and try to come up with one. =)

Comment: @EtanReisner Exactly why I went with what I did! I'd be interested to see it though if you do come up with one.